# The method getColumnName in ResultSetMeta can't return right name of column (jdbc)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to get table label of column .like string display in mysql. Like this
[image]
However, when I use getColumnName, It turn out there is some difference  between returned string and  below string.  Like this:
[image]
But It is right in Variables explorer in eclipse when I debug, Like this:
 [image]
I can't find other way to get column. It seem returned string is `originalColumnName`, but how to get `ColumnName`? Anyone know how to fix it?

There is my code, I know there is other problem in code. Please just assume the type of all column is String.

```
      public ResultSet DisplayShowTables() throws SQLException
  {
      ResultSet Res = Sta.executeQuery("DESC Code2Name");
      ResultSetMetaData ResMeta = Res.getMetaData();
      String [] ColumnName = new String [ResMeta.getColumnCount()];
      int MetaCount = ResMeta.getColumnCount();
      for (int i = 0; i < MetaCount; i++) {
          ColumnName [i] =  ResMeta.getColumnName(i+1);
    }
      String LeftAlignFormat = "|";
      String Separator = "+";
      for (int i = 0; i < MetaCount; i++) {
          LeftAlignFormat = LeftAlignFormat.concat(" %-20s |");
          Separator =Separator.concat("----------------------+");
    }
      LeftAlignFormat = LeftAlignFormat.concat("%n");
      Separator = Separator.concat("%n");
      if(Res.isBeforeFirst()){
            System.out.format(Separator);
            System.out.format(LeftAlignFormat, ColumnName);
            System.out.format(Separator);   
        }
      while (Res.next()) {
        Vector<String> RowData = new Vector<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < MetaCount; i++) {
            RowData.add(Res.getString(i+1).toString());
        }
        System.out.format(LeftAlignFormat, RowData);
    }
        if(Res.isAfterLast())
            System.out.format(Separator);
      return Res;
  }
```

Comment: It seem returned string is originalColumnName, but how to get ColumnName?

Comment: To get that you probably need to use `getColumnLabel` (which is what you need to use anyway in most cases).

Comment: That is right. getColumnLabel really work. thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `DESC` is just a shortcut for a query of the information schema with aliases for the columns.

Column aliases can be retrieved with [`ResultSetMetadata.getColumnLabel(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel-int-).

JDBC defines column label as:

> Gets the designated column's suggested title for use in printouts and displays. The suggested title is usually specified by the SQL `AS` clause. If a SQL `AS` is not specified, the value returned from `getColumnLabel` will be the same as the value returned by the `getColumnName` method.

This also means that in almost all situation you should be using `getColumnLabel` instead of `getColumnName`.