# Why can't I analyze SHOW TABLES result in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

The following code causes an exception `SQLException: Column index out of range.`

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ListingTablesTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {


      Connection conn = null;
      Statement stmt = null;

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/library","java","");

      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES;");

      ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();

      String columnName = "";

      for(int i=0; i<md.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
         columnName = md.getColumnName(i);
         System.out.println(String.format("Column #%d is %s", i, columnName));
      }


      int j = 0;
      while(rs.next()){
         System.out.println(String.format("Table #%d is %s", j, rs.getString(columnName)));
         j++;
      }

   }
}
```

Why?

**UPDATE**

After I fixed column numbering:

```
  for(int i=1; i<=md.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
     columnName = md.getColumnName(i);
     System.out.println(String.format("Column #%d is %s", i, columnName));
  }
```

I got single column named 'TABLE_NAME' and this name does not work in next loop saying `SQLException: Column 'TABLE_NAME' not found.`

In MySQL console column is named `Tables_in_library`, not `TABLE_NAME`:

```
mysql> use library;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_library |
+-------------------+
| author            |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column retrieval in JDBC uses a 1-based index. You are attempting to get column 0, which doesn't exist.

You need to use:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= md.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    columnName = md.getColumnName(i);
    System.out.println(String.format("Column #%d is %s", i, columnName));
}
```

The second part of your question is a duplicate [The method getColumnName in ResultSetMeta can't return right name of column (jdbc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038258/the-method-getcolumnname-in-resultsetmeta-cant-return-right-name-of-column-jdb) (the TL;DR version: you need to use `getColumnLabel(..)` instead of `getColumnName(..)`).

Comment: I have a right to use only last column name found, why not? How is it illogical?

Comment: @Dims Of course you are allowed to do that, but I don't really see the point, you could also just have done `getColumnLabel(md.getColumnCount())` to get the last column (or if you are only interested in the value: `getString(md.getColumnCount())` without even bothering to retrieve the label/name.

Comment: @Dims BTW Note that the idiomatic way in JDBC to retrieve tables is to use [`DatabaseMetaData.getTables`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-)